# Random numbers are the same every time function is called

Tags: c++, c++11, random

The numbers are random every time I run the program, but they stay the same during that same run. I want the numbers to be random every time the function is called.
I did seed the generator in main().

```
    std::random_device device;
    std::mt19937 generator(device());
```

My function

```
void takeAssignment(std::vector<Student> &students,
                    const int min, const int max,
                    std::mt19937 e)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(min, max);
    // all students take the assignment
    for (auto &s : students)
    {
        // random performance
        int score{dist(e)};
        s.addScore(score, max);
        std::cout << s.getName() << "'s score: " << score << std::endl;
    }
}
```

For example, everytime the function was called with the min as 0 and max as 10,
the output of the function printed

```
Abril Soto's score: 1
Bailey Case's score: 9
```

during that run.

Putting dist inside the loop didn't work either, the numbers stayed the same.

Comment: Typo: change `std::mt19937 e)` to `std::mt19937 & e)`  It's taking a copy of the generator and not updating the one being passed in as the parameter.

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks! I thought about that but didn't think it would fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing generator via call by value, thereby creating a copy with no seed and generating same values. Try passing by reference in function argument: like

`std::mt19937& e`

Comment: *Every* `std::mt19937` has *a* state. These `std::mt19937` all have the *same* initial state